# Steady state of a system of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, self-learning, mathematical-modeling

I have a system of four ordinary differential equation. This is a modelling problem we were also meant to criticize some of the issues with the way the problem was presented. Its meant to describe the nitrogen concentration in the available nutrients for an ecosystem. 
Where $N_c= N+P+Z+D = constant $

$$
\frac{dN}{dt} = -ulP\frac{N}{K_s + N} +aD + (1- \mu)hPZ\\ 
\frac{dP}{dt} = ulP\frac{N}{K_s + N} - hPZ - sP\\
\frac{dZ}{dt} = \mu hPZ -eZ \\
\frac{dD}{dt} = eZ +sP -aD
$$

Apart from $N,P,Z,D$ we consider all other terms constant. I note we were not given an explanation to all the other terms.

We were told there were four steady solutions, two of which are relatively easy to find. I am struggling to understand how to find steady solutions. Could anybody please help with these ? Thanks not experienced with differentials.

Edit: Helpful Reference for contextualization http://mpe.dimacs.rutgers.edu/2013/11/26/ocean-plankton-and-ordinary-differential-equations/

Comment: steady solutions means that the derivative is zero. So, you are left with four algebraic equaitons.

Comment: @RonnyLandsverk I am aware of this I have tried to solve it but keep messing up the system and getting nowhere

Comment: To get help, I guess you should write which parameters are constants. I guess the right-hand side are complex ?

Comment: Is there a typo here? Is one of the $\frac{dN}{dt}$ supposed to be a $\frac{dZ}{dt}$ ? Also are the capital $I$ in the first two equations supposed to just be $i$ ?

Comment: Also dumping a lot of symbols with no explanations as to what any of them are is a little inconsiderate. Take the time to explain where they came from, what they mean, and any restrictions on the constants to be aware of.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you for your comments I am going to fix this.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes there is a typo in the third ODE.

Comment: @RonnyLandsverk i its just a constant, not a complex number.

Comment: Writing up the answer, this is still not enough explanation. What values are the constants allowed to take on? If they can be anything, there is more than $4$ steady state solutions

Comment: @NinadMunshi We are within all honesty not given any reference values for the constants. Hence my confusion of getting 2 solutions "relatively easy" way being a beginner. All the problem information is as above.

Comment: Based on your knowledge of the topic, is it allowable for the constants to be $0$ ?

Comment: Also, if you could check the $P$ and $p$'s in the equations, I'd appreciate it. I suspect, but I'm not confident, of a few typos there.

Comment: $N$ always appears on the RHS in the combination $ulP\frac{N}{K_s+N}$. So you could replace this combination with another variable called eg $M$. ...  If $p$ the same as $P$? Is $u$ the same as $\mu$? You seem to have a lot of parameters here.

Comment: @NinadMunshi  I am adding a reference related to the problem in question. But  we have the variable $D$ in addition which corresponds to the solid waste products which can break down to release nutrients. I am not sure if we can just set all constant terms to zero.  We are asked to handle this with realistic assumptions about the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume none of the constants is $0$.

From equation 2, either $P=0$ or $Z = ((u l - s) N - K_s s)/((N +K_s) h)$.

From equation 3, either $Z=0$ or $P = e/(\mu h)$.

One case is $P=Z=0$.  Then from the last equation $D=0$, and the first equation is automatically true, so $N$ is arbitrary.

Another case is $P = e/(\mu h)$, $Z = ((u l - s) N - K_s s)/((N +K_s) h)$.
Then we get 
$$ D={\frac {e \left(  \left( s + \mu u l - \mu\,s \right) N+K_{{s}}\mu
\,s-K_{{s}}s \right) }{ah\mu\, \left( K_{{s}}+N \right) }}
$$
and $N$ is arbitrary.

The third case is $Z = 0$ and $(u l - s) N - K_s s = 0$, i.e. $N = K_s s/(u l - s)$.  Then from the last equation $P = aD/s$, and $D$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:  The sum of RHS of the four equations is zero (since derivative of a constant ). When simplified, $P=0$. From the second equation $Z=0$.

We are left with two equations

$$\frac{dD}{dt}= -aD,\, \frac{dN}{dt}= aD,\, $$

so that by adding

$$ N+D= const. $$

and the two dependent variables stay indeterminate.

Comment: what simplifications led you to $P=0$? Sorry this is not clear to me.

Comment: The sum of the right sides is $2sP$, so either $s=0$ or $P=0$.  If $s=0$ you get steady solutions with $P$ arbitrary, $N=Z=D=0$.

Comment: But since you say you want $N+P+Z+D=$constant, maybe one of the $sP$ terms should be $-sP$ to make the sum of the right sides $0$.  Otherwise $N+P+Z+D$ will not be constant unless $P$ is always $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes that is a typo! Back to square one. I was going to check this again after reading your comment !

Comment: @Narasimham I am sorry as pointed out by Robert Israel there was a typo in equation 2.